# Syntactic characterisation of the intersection of CTL and LTL

Tags: linear-temporal-logic

The Baier and Katoen textbook references this paper

> E. M. Clarke and I. A. Draghicescu. Expressibility results for
>   linear-time and branching-time logics, pages 428–437. Springer Berlin
>   Heidelberg, Berlin, Heidelberg, 1989.

to say that, given a CTL formula P, *if there exists* an equivalent LTL one, it can be obtained by dropping all branch quantifiers (i.e. A and E) from P.

Is there a syntactic criterion that provides a guarantee that if a CTL formula passes the test, then an equivalent LTL formula *does exist*?

Comment: The first intuition is that if all the path quantifiers are `A`
(after pushing negations to the atomic propositions) then there is an LTL equivalent. However, this does not work. Consider `AF AG p`. If there were an LTL equivalent, it would have to be `F G p`. However, this latter is not expressible in CTL. (Thanks also to @Shaull.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the same question on [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_a_syntactic_criterion_on_CTL_formulae_that_guarantees_the_existence_of_an_equivalent_LTL_formula) and got pointers to two very interesting papers—thanks to [Igor Konnov](http://forsyte.at/people/konnov/) and [Paul Attie](http://www.cs.aub.edu.lb/pa07/). I will summarise here the information from the papers, relevant to the question, but first, here are the two papers:

1. Monika Maidl. "The common fragment of CTL and LTL," Proceedings of the 41st Annual Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science. pp. 643-652, 2000.
    http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/SFCS.2000.892332
2. Mikołaj Bojańczyk. "The common fragment of ACTL and LTL." International Conference on Foundations of Software Science and Computational Structures. pp. 172-185, 2008.
    http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-78499-9_13

The paper by Monika Maidl does, indeed, provide an answer very much along the lines I was looking for.

Maidl considers ACTL—"the fragment of those CTL formulas that contain, when in negation normal form, only A as a quantifier." She characterises the fragment of ACTL that is expressible in LTL, denoted by ACTL<sup>det</sup>, where "det" stands for "deterministic". ACTL<sup>det</sup> is defined inductively:

1. state predicates are in ACTL<sup>det</sup>;
2. for ACTL<sup>det</sup> formulas φ1 and φ2 and a predicate p, the formulae

   - `φ1 ∧ φ2` ,
   - `AX φ1`,
   - `(p ∧ φ1) ∨ (¬p ∧ φ2 )`,
   - `A (p ∧ φ1 ) U (¬p ∧ φ2)`,
   - `A (p ∧ φ1) W (¬p ∧ φ2)`

   all belong to ACTL<sup>det</sup>.

Furthermore, Maidl makes the following remark: "For an ACTL<sup>det</sup> formula φ, [the formula] `A φ W p` can be expressed in ACTL<sup>det</sup> , since `A φ W p ⇔ A (φ ∧ ¬p) W p`. A special case is `AG φ`. Similarly, `A φ U p` can be expressed in ACTL<sup>det</sup>."

In this paper, the class LTL<sup>det</sup> of formulae equivalent to the ACTL<sup>det</sup> ones. is characterised as "[t]hose LTL formulas the negation of which can be represented by a 1-weak Büchi automaton." In the second paper, Mikołaj Bojańczyk argues that this characterisation "was not known to [be] effective, i.e. there was no algorithm that decided if `¬φ` could be recognized by [a] restricted Büchi automaton." He then provides such an algorithm.

Furthermore, Bojańczyk provides an example, showing that the common fragment of LTL and CTL is not limited to ACTL: "a very simple LTL property, “all paths belong to (ab)<sup>∗</sup>a(ab)<sup>∗</sup>c<sup>ω</sup>”, can be defined in CTL but not ACTL."

Answer (score 1):

Note that by "equivalent", we actually need to interpret LTL over trees. Thus, we say that a CTL formula $\phi$ is equivalent to an LTL formula $\psi$, if $\phi$ is equivalent to the CTL* formula $A\psi$.

Thus, we essentially compare LTL and CTL in the common grounds of CTL*.

Given this, it's not hard to construct a procedure to check the equivalent. Simply check whether the formula $\phi \iff A\psi$ is a tautology in CTL*. This can be done in 2EXPTIME. However, since satisfiability of CTL is only EXPTIME complete, it might be possible to reduce this to EXPTIME (but I haven't given it much thought).

Comment: This provides a procedure for checking whether a CTL formula has an LTL equivalent:
1. Take a CTL formula ϕ;  
2. Remove the branch quantifiers to obtain an LTL formula ψ;
3. Check whether ϕ⟺Aψ is a tautology in CTL*.
If yes, then ψ is equivalent to ϕ. However, the question is whether there is a way to characterise (at least some) CTL formulae, for which this will be guaranteed to work. Say, if all branch quantifiers in ϕ are `A` and `some other condition` holds, then ψ as above is guaranteed to be equivalent to ϕ without having to perform the step 3.