# Algorithm to decide if a CTL formula can also be expressed in LTL and translate it?

Tags: temporal-logic, linear-temporal-logic

So I'm trying to solve some CTL formulas on a given system using model-checking.

I'm trying several different solvers; some of them only accept LTL as input, but have some nice partial-order reductions built-in that I would like to use and should perform well on my systems that feature heavy interleaving.

We know the intersection of LTL and CTL is non-empty (e.g. invariants lie there) but do you know of an algorithm to determine if a CTL formula can also be expressed in LTL, and to translate it if so ?

Comment: This question actually has a close duplicate here : https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/36626/syntactic-characterisation-of-the-intersection-of-ctl-and-ltl?rq=1 that I didn't find before

Comment: Doesn't it fully answer your question?

Comment: It does, although there does not seem to be an implementation and the algorithm is more costly than I hoped. But I'm not sure how to close my question. I don't have rep enough on this stack to "mark as duplicate" and kill the question outright.